# Get size of base64 image without saving it

Tags: php, image, base64

How to get the size in bytes (for example 450000 bytes) of a base64 image without saving it using `imagecreatefromstring` with PHP?

Comment: Please explain me the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess would be that you asked how to do something without showing any attempt to try for yourself. What did you investigate, what have you found.

Comment: @Hammerstein please try google "get size base64 image php". You'll find only how to get width and height and not the size like 150kb.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php) can do this for you..It returns the  information about a string buffer.So it is reliable to `imagecreatefromstring()`

```
$encoded_string = "the string";
$imgdata = base64_decode($encoded_string);
$f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Comment: -1 it's returns MIME_TYPE not the file size (for example 120kb).

Comment: you need change the parameter from finfo_buffer

Comment: There are no constants for file size: http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php